# Speech training files and registry locations

Tags: sapi, speech

I have a speech project that requires acoustic training to be done in code. I a successfully able to create training files with transcripts and their associated registry entries under Windows 7 using SAPI. However, I am unable to determine if the Recognition Engine is successfully using these files and adapting its model. My questions are as follows:

1. When performing training through the Control Panel training UI, the system stores the training files in "{AppData}\Local\Microsoft\Speech\Files\TrainingAudio". Do the audio training files HAVE to be stored in this location, or can I store them elsewhere as long as the registry entries for the profile reflect the correct path?

   1. The Speech Control Panel creates registry entries for the training audio files in the key "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Speech\RecoProfiles\Tokens{ProfileGUID}{00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000000000}\Files".

   a) Do the registry entries created by my training code HAVE to be placed in "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000000000}\Files" or can I create a new random GUID under {ProfileGUID}?

   b) Does the subkey HAVE to be named "Files"?

   c) And do the registry values HAVE to follow the form "TrainingAudio-xxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx" or can I use other values?

   d) Finally, the Registry Value Data is of the form "%1c%\Microsoft\Speech\Files\TrainingAudio\SP-xxx....xxx". Can I specify an absolute path?

   e) Do the file names HAVE to follow the form "SP-xxx....xxx.wav" or can I use any unique file names?

Thanks.

Giri

Comment: To the first part of your question, yes you can point the registry to other locations and store your audio files there. If you want to check if adaption is occurring, maybe try doing training with a friend or someone with a thick accent. You should see the differences easily.