# How to use the function GetStorageFileName for adding training files to registry?

Tags: windows, speech-recognition, sapi

I am using sapi 5.4 and I am able to retain the audio for training  but for adding it to registry  entries as given in this [Acoustic training using SAPI 5.3 Speech API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299799/acoustic-training-using-sapi-5-3-speech-api?rq=1)  I am not able to understand the arguments to be used for ISpObjectToken::GetStorageFileName can somebody help me out with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ISpObjectToken::GetStorageFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms718252%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) isn't the best documented API in the world.  Luckily, I have some worked examples to help improve the documentation.

*clsidCaller*

Set this if you need the file name associated with the object token.  For training, this should be `CLSID_NULL`.  (If you're updating engine-related data, then it would be the CLSID of the engine.)

*pszValueName*

The name of the registry subkey to store the filename in.  For training, this should be `L"TrainingAudio-<locale>"`, where locale should be the 4 digit locale ID for the engine.

*pszFileNameSpecifier*

The name of the file to be created.

If this starts with "X:\" or "\" it is assumed to be a full path.

Otherwise it is assumed to be relative to the special folder ID given in the nFolder parameter.

If pszFileNameSpecifier ends with a '\', or is NULL a unique file name will be created.

If the name contains a %d the %d is replaced by a number to give a unique file name.

For training, you should specify something like `L"TrainingAudio\\TR_%d.wav".`

*nFolder*

A CSIDL value that identifies the folder whose path is to be retrieved. The user can force the creation of a folder by combining the folder's CSIDL with CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE. If pszFileNameSpecifier is NULL or "\", nFolder must have a specified CSIDL folder combined with CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE if the user wants to force to create the file.

For training, this should be `CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA | CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE`.

*ppszFilePath*

Address of a pointer to the null-terminated string that receives the file path information. Use CoTaskMemFree to release the string when done.

Comment: I just want to point out that CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA = 28, and CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE = 32768, for anyone programming in c#.